# want to upload image using child kendo grid to parent kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Process - 1)upload image in child grid 2) after that, if i want to set image as a parent grid image then click on link button 3) set this image as a parent kendo grid image box.

Note - i have already use "Datetime.Ticks" methods, but its working 10 out of 5 time. FYI pls find 1 image. -just click on selected Red button. so Image transfer Child To parent. Image 2 - Code line. parent grid.

thanks.

Image 1)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp3zd.jpg

Image 2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6WFG.jpg

Comment: You are asking for the entire implementation?

Comment: @ Anastasios Selmanis, i got an answer for that....code level changes. Kendo grid have "Read" method.i called same function using "Read" method. so its solve.